# How do I store meta data in pdf which can only be edited by my application?

Tags: metadata, pdfbox

I have implemented functionality in my application to allow user to draw clouds by drawing various adjacent semi circles using pdfbox library. I need information regarding the locations of these clouds, to detect whether the user's click location corresponds to a cloud.Since, the pdfbox library doesn't give me any information regarding location of these clouds, I store their location in pdf's meta data field using the following code(while the cloud is being drawn).

```
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDMetadata pdMetaData = catalog.getMetadata();
// Code to append new metadata to previous stored meta data.
java.io.InputStream newData = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newMetaData)); 
PDMetadata newPDMetadata = new PDMetadata(doc, newData, false);
 catalog.setMetadata(newPDMetadata);
```

I store the location data as xml in the metadata field.And, when new location data is to be stored, I extract the previous meta data and add a new xml tag corresponding to the new cloud location.And again store the xml in the pdf's meta data field.But, the problem with this approach is that pdf's meta data field will be overwritten, in case the user uses some other pdf  editor, which might store some data in the meta data field.
Is there a way to store metadata in pdf as key value pair.So, that it can only be edited, by a person who knows the key corresponding the data, just like websites store cookies.

Comment: According to the PDF specification *the format of the XML representing the metadata is defined as part of a framework called the Extensible Metadata Platform (XMP) and described in the Adobe document XMP: Extensible Metadata Platform.* Do you honor that specification when you create and append your metadata?

Comment: That been said, you can add new entries nearly everywhere, and if you use a key with a prefix you registered as per Annex E of the PDF specification, that entry shouldn't collide with anybody else's PDF use.

Comment: My thought is similar to the 2nd comment of mkl. For example, do this: `page.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.get("yourname"), yourstuff);`

Comment: What's the purpose of that cloud? Could you use an annotation for that purpose? If yes then the position information is available from the annotation object.

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun No cloud is a feature the application, to allow user to highlight something.Also, I couldn't find any pdf annotation for cloud.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr and mkl thanks .Your suggestions worked.Only modification is that I used getCOSDictionary instead of getCOSObject,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which solved my problem:

```
int pageNum = 0;
PDPage page = (PDPage)doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(pageNum);
COSName markupMetadataElement = COSName.getPDFName(Key);
COSDictionary dictionary = page.getCOSDictionary();
COSString newCosString = new COSString(newMetaData);
dictionary.setItem(markupMetadataElement, newCosString);
```